# How to write multiple columns in a loop in c++?

Tags: c++, file

Suppose I have a loop:

```cpp
for(int i=1; i<=1024; i++)
```

I want to fill a file with 128 columns (not rows!), so the first column contains numbers from 1 to 8, second from 9 to 16 and so on and so forth.

Comment: Have you tried any more code than the `for` line? If so, please post what you have tried.

Comment: What are you even going to use for your columns (not rows!)

Comment: I think he asks about the modulo operator.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make two loops - the first by lines and nested by columns - and then calculate numbers with easy math expression.
E.g.:

```cpp
    for(int line = 0; line < 8; line++)
    {
        for( int col = 0; col < 128; col++)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << line + col * 8 + 1;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

`setw()` has parameter 5 to make identical width for colums with numbers from 1 to 1024

**EDITED:**

If you want to use only one `for` loop and exact as you give in the question, you can use more complicated math expressions.
First, let's calculate number of line as `(i-1) / 128` (numbers start from 0) and number of column as `(i-1) % 128` (numbers from 0 to 127). And now you can make the following loop with additional new-line-conditional output:

```cpp
    for(int i=1; i<=1024; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << ( 1 + 8 * ((i-1) % 128) ) + ( (i-1) / 128 );
        if( i % 128 == 0 ) // new line once per 128 numbers
            cout << endl;
    }
```

Of course if you want to make file, you should do something with the output - redirect standard output to file or change `cout` to other stream.

Answer (score 0):

The items for each columns are just 8i to 8i+7. You can write mutiple loops.`for(int i = 0; i< 128;i++)
for(int j = 0; j <8;j++) 
int k = 8* i+ j;`

Answer (score 0):

```
void write_in_file( ofstream &fout, int start){
   for(int i = 1; i <= 128; i++){
     fout<<start <<"\t";
     start+=8;
   }
   fout<<"\n";
}
int main(){
  ofstream fout;
  fout.open("out.txt");
  for(int i=1;i<=8;i++){
    write_in_file(fout,i);
  }
}
```

Explanation:
As we need 8 rows so we call function write_in_file 8 times. Each time function write_in_file writes 128 entries in the file.